"Security violation" Issue during boot (Rufus)
I have had this laptop for a while, and it sucks.
It is the hp laptop 15-dy273dx
I'm having an issue that hasn't been here before. It would boot into Zorin installer fine when etched with rufus, but i recently tried using ventoy, in which i first got the issue "Security violation" and the error code 0x1A. I switched back to rufus, but the issue prolonged. Now i'm just wondering, is there a way to fix this without disabling secure boot. There has not been any changes to the UEFI other than CMOS reset due to checksum issue

Zorin is not an official flavor of Ubuntu.

"Security Violation" usually means that whatever UEFI bootloader you are trying to boot failed Secure Boot validation.
This can mean one of few things:

The bootloaders that Zorin use are not Secure Boot signed (there are quite a few distros out there that are not compatible with Secure Boot so it's not that uncommon).
The bootloaders that Zorin use have been revoked for whatever reason (for instance, there was a GRUB vulnerability a few years ago that caused older versions of GRUB UEFI bootloaders to be revoked, and if you try to boot a distro that uses these old GRUB bootloaders, you will get a Security Violation)
Your image or media is corrupted.
Your laptop manufacturer is in bed with Microsoft and has been applying the super-obnoxious "two tier policy" for Secure Boot, that Microsoft is currently trying to push, where there are 2 versions of Secure Boot that can be enabled, one for Microsoft Windows bootloaders ONLY and one for Microsoft Windows bootloaders plus other regular Secure Boot signed bootloaders.

If your media was created by Rufus, it should only be one of the above, and you  will have to either figure out which it is, or disable Secure Boot.
